# Pyramid templates always reload (cook) on Openshift Server on refresh

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, openshift

I have built Python 3.3 Pyramid 1.5 app on Openshift.

On my local development system, when I refresh the page, the templates only reload (cook) once after I start the server like they should. On the production server (Openshift) the templates ALWAYS reload (cook) every time I refresh the page.  The templates have not changed and thus should not reload.

The 'reload_templates' config variable is set to 'false' in both development and production ini files. See the configuration below.

Any idea why the templates always reload (cook) on page refresh on my Openshift app?

my development.ini and production.ini are both set to the below settings.

```
pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
```

EDIT: Here is how I start my pyramid app on Openshift (following their basic startup)

app.py starts when the OPENSHIFT server starts

app.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import imp
    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    zapp = imp.load_source('main_production_no_pserve', 'myapp/__init__.py')

    print('Starting Waitress Server on %s:%d ... ' % (ip, port))
    run_waitress(zapp.main_production_no_pserve, ip, port)
```

**init**.py

```
def main_production_no_pserve(environ, start_response):
    settings = {
            'pyramid.reload_templates': 'false',
            'pyramid.debug_authorization': 'false',
            'pyramid.debug_notfound':  'false',
            'pyramid.debug_routematch': 'false',
            'pyramid.default_locale_name':  'en'
    }
    config = app_configuration(settings)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()(environ, start_response)
    return app


def app_configuration(settings):

    config = Configurator(authentication_policy=authentication_policy,
                          authorization_policy=authorization_policy,
                          settings=settings)

    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')                      
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('Home_View', '/')

   config.add_subscriber('subscribers.handle_my_response','pyramid.events.NewResponse')
    config.set_request_factory(myrequest)                        
    config.scan('myapp.views')                        
    return config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was starting the server on the Openshift. The old method gave the illusion of working but really didn't in the long run.  New code below:

```
def main_production_no_pserve (global_config, **settings):
    settings = {
            'pyramid.reload_templates': 'true',
            'pyramid.debug_authorization': 'false',
            'pyramid.debug_notfound':  'false',
            'pyramid.debug_routematch': 'false',
            'pyramid.default_locale_name':  'en'
    }
    config = app_configuration(settings)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
   return app



if __name__ == '__main__':

    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    app = main_production_no_pserve(global_config=None)
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host=ip, port=port, threads=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

[Environment Variables and .ini File Settings](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/master/narr/environment.html#environment-chapter)

> Where a configuration file setting exists with the same meaning as an environment variable, and both are present at application startup time, the environment variable setting takes precedence.

Also I am not sure about the precedence of using `--reload` against `.ini` settings.  What command do you use to launch your server?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have read up on the link you provided which seemed like a solid lead.  However,  I couldn't find any conflicting environment variables.  I have added how I start the app in my post above.  I use Openshifts method of start up (same on my dev system) so I can use their RHC tools suite.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The Pyramid Cookbook has a [few suggestions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/expresscloud.html).  Alternatively, there is this [list of other cloud providers and deployment options](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/index.html).